# Fixing compile this to undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

My app.js is written in es6 standard and my question is >
How can I use code like this?:

```
$('img').each(() => {
    var title = $(this).attr('src');
    titles.push(title);
});
```

I observed that node compile this code to:

```
'use strict';

$('img').each(function () {
    var title = $(undefined).attr('src');
    titles.push(title);
});
```

compile 'this' to 'undefined', how can I fix that?
thx in advance ;)

Comment: Please read [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use the element passed to the callback, as defined in the [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) documentation - Function ( Integer index, Element element ):

```js
var titles = [];

$('img').each((index, element) => {
    var title = $(element).attr('src');
    titles.push(title);
});

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(titles, undefined, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_502c67b98956_64.png">

<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/62c7e8f531e824f6f8da34453cdd698a8856f3aea36118408c3e5c09.png?9e884f0299eee37aedab60fe1ed363b5">

<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions bind the `this` value lexically - see [MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> Since this is already bound lexically, invoking an arrow function
>   through the call() or apply() methods can only pass in arguments, but
>   has no effect on this:

You can fix it by simply using a plain old function :)